# Renewing Apple Certificates

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, xcode8

As usual, Apple's over-complicated procedures are driving me mad.

We have an app that uses Push Notifications (amongst other certificates). This ran out 2 months ago but we have been unable to get a new certificate working which is, needless to say, ridiculous.

I have added new certificates to the Apple ID Developer account, generated p12 files, added to Keychain, converted to .pem file, etc but the app still fails. I don't know if we are generating the wrong certificate or storing in wrong place or not linking it to app etc.

Can someone please make themselves a hero for all us standard app developers by listing the full and precise steps to getting new certificates found by Xcode and the app build?

Thanks.

**LATEST**

Ok so still a duff app. Have cleared certificates, made new provisioning profile, made new certificates, added to keychain, copied to system keychain (whatever that is but they seemed to be there before)....

Errors are as follows.

Target > Capabilities > Push Notifications

Target > General > Signing

Both say 'Provisioning profile "xxxxxx" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: xxxxx. (M........6)'

Don't know what I should be doing with anything after adding to Keychain and no idea why I can't add certificates to a profile. Push Notifications is enabled on App ID.

Comment: Whenever you update the certificates, also update the provisioning profiles as well.

Comment: Thx Mila - All profiles expire in 2018 but stated as invalid - go figure - so now all active but still no good - do i need to do anything with the downloaded provisioning profiles or do I now need to redo all certificates? going round in circles here all the for sake of a simple 'renew' button in apple....

Comment: have toggled automatic Xcode signing and no difference - app builds and runs in sim but push crashes it

Comment: Of course I now have multiple certificates for everything cos downloaded so many times.... not sure what issues that causes either but nothing ever works

Comment: Xcode now says... 'Provisioning profile "......." doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: ....... (.......)' - assume thats an issue but no idea how to fix as fixing that probably causes other issues

Comment: I have 4.5 years of experience in iOS and never get Certificate issue as I never choose automatic signing process.

Comment: yup i never use it either but still impossible to renew/update my certificates

Comment: Start a fresh, delete everything from your mac even from Trash, restart the system.
Create a fresh certificate on Developer Portal, then Push certificate and finally update the provisioning profile, try naming provisioning with different name everytime you update provisioning. I use version number as suffix.
Finally install the certificates share the PEM file, install the provisioning and then it should work.

Comment: ok thx - have tried that but 1) don't know how to add all certificates to provisioning profile, 2) unsure what 'share the PEM' means, and 3) unsure what 'install' certificates/provisioning means :)

Comment: Check in your keychain access certificate contains private key or Not if its not containts private key then problem with generating certificate.

Comment: @vishal - all certificates in keychain have private key associated - not sure if key name has to be the profile name but who knows

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.moengage.com/v1.0/docs/apns-certificate-pem-file) is the full and precise steps to getting new certificates you want.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: have followed this up until the MoEngage dashboard bit as that seems to be specific to whatever MoEngage is - what do I do with my .pem file within Xcode/app?

Comment: The `.pem` file is used in your `push notification Server.` You need to find the `.pem` file on your server and replace it.